# UIAlertView dismiss on return

Tags: ios, keyboard, uialertview, textfield, dismiss

I'm having a problem with my search alert when using the search-tab. When someone is typing their search-string and hit return it will only dismiss the keyboard and you still have to tab the "Search" (Zoek) button do actually start a websearch.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
if( [inputText length] >= 1 )
{
    [searchview addSubview:indicator];
    NSString *urlAddress= @"http://www.sportdirect.com/articles?search=";
    urlAddress =[urlAddress stringByAppendingString:inputText];
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [searchview loadRequest:requestObj];
    [[searchview scrollView] setBounces: NO];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"Voerde zoekopdracht uit"];

}
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
[_message dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(0) animated:YES];
NSString *inputText = [[_message textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
if( [inputText length] >= 1 )
{
    [searchview addSubview:indicator];
    NSString *urlAddress= @"http://www.sportdirect.com/articles?search=";
    urlAddress =[urlAddress stringByAppendingString:inputText];
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [searchview loadRequest:requestObj];
    [[searchview scrollView] setBounces: NO];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"Voerde zoekopdracht uit"];

}

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

Does anyone know how to actually do a search as soon as the return button on the keyboard is tabbed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class needs to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` to get the keyboard return callback. As suggested by borrden, this can be done as follows

```
[message textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
```

Then implement this method,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Dismiss the alert view 
    // Initiate the search
    return YES;
}
```

Use this `UIAlertView` method. Refer [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW18)

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Call this on your alert view instance when required to dismiss it programmatically. You would require to keep `message` as an ivar to access it when required.

Hope that helps!

Comment: First you will have to set the textfield delegate to your view controller, so that you know when the return button was presed.  You can get this via `[message textFieldAtIndex:0]`

Comment: @borrrden Indeed, let me add that to my answer.

Comment: this is not an answer for the question : "Does anyone know how to actually do a search as soon as the return button on the keyboard is tabbed?" . This is an answer for UIAlertView clicked button

Comment: @incmiko I believe now its okay?

Comment: Yeah, that will work I think.  As a style choice, I would recommend simply calling a third method from both locations (alert button and keyboard).  I'm not sure if the delegate methods are called if you dismiss an alert view like that, but I haven't tried it so it may.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I used those methods but when I hit return it won't dismiss.. I've made a property of UIAlertView *message and did this within the textFieldShouldReturn: `_message dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(1) animated:YES];
    NSString *inputText = [[_message textFieldAtIndex:0] text];`

Comment: @JoranDenHouting Is your text field delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn` getting called? Also pass button index 0 in `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` method without the `()`.

Comment: @Amar I just updated my OP with the code I'm using right now. I think I'm going in a totally wrong direction and didn't really understand how to use the `textFieldShouldReturn`..

Comment: @JoranDenHouting You need to set the textfield delegate before showing the alertview. I can't see where you have done that. Once you do it, the `textFieldShouldReturn` should get fired.

Comment: `- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIAlertView *message = XXXXX
    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [message textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
    [message show];
}` so, just before the "SHOW"

Comment: @JoranDenHouting Why are you declaring another `UIAlertView *message`? Use the property you declared. Like `self.message = [[UIAlertView alloc] init..];` Then use the same property to call dismiss. Also move the dismiss call to end of the function just before the `return NO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `UITextField` delegate method:

your class must implement `UITextFieldDelegate`. set `textField.delegate = self;`

After implement this method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
{
  // here you can write what you want, for example search

  [textField resignFirstResponder];

  return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```